# nested defaultdict based on a key inside dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, defaultdict

I'm trying to create a defaultdict within a defaultdict based on a key value. My thinking may be completely wrong here, but here's the code for a basic defaultdict;

```
def record():
    return {
        'count': 0,
        'key1': Counter(),      
    }

1_record = defaultdict(record)
```

But what if I want to add a key as a defaultdict like this;

```
def record():
    return {
        'count': 0,
        'key1': Counter(),
        'key2': {
            'count': 0,
            'nested_key1': Counter()

    }
}
```

In the above how could I  make 'key2' a defaultdict? Is this even possible or am I approaching the problem the wrong way?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `defaultdict(record)`, without the `()`?

Comment: yup, sorry edited typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely can have a "recursive" defaultdict:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> def record():
...   return {
...     'key': defaultdict(record)
...   }
... 
>>> d = defaultdict(record)
>>> 
>>> d['foo']
{'key': defaultdict(<function record at 0x10b396f50>, {})}
>>> d['foo']['key']['bar']
{'key': defaultdict(<function record at 0x10b396f50>, {})}
>>> d
defaultdict(<function record at 0x10b396f50>, {'foo': {'key': defaultdict(<function record at 0x10b396f50>, {'bar': {'key': defaultdict(<function record at 0x10b396f50>, {})}})}})
```

However, swapping out the names of the keys at different levels would probably require some special-casing and would make the code a bit more messy...

Comment: Hey mgilson, could you check my edit? I tried a recursive dict but it gave me an error, do you see anything wrong in my code/approach?

Comment: It looks like the `defaultdict` bit is working just fine... `dict_record['hello']['key2']` is a "`defaultdict(second_record)`" so `dict_record['hello']['key2']['another_hello']` is a return value from `second_record` (a `dict`) and you can't add `1` to a `dict`.